# Why Earliest Due Date is not guaranteed to be optimal?

Tags: optimization, operations-research

The [Earliest Due Date rule](https://www.demandsolutions.com/resource-center/supply-chain-glossary/supply-chain-glossary-e/earliest-due-date-(edd)-or-edd.html) is when jobs are scheduled according to the earliest due date given, this is supposed to minimize the total tardiness of the whole jobs.

But the earliest due date rule is not supposed to be optimal, ie it does not guarantee the minimal tardiness possible.

Can someone help me understand why this is the case, **if not can someone provide a simple example where scheduling via the Earliest Due Date does not give the minimum tardiness**

Comment: I thought EDD was intended to minimize the maximum tardiness only, though I've forgotten the details.  [here](http://www.allsyllabus.com/aj/note/Computer_Science/Operations%20Management/GSP/Earliest%20Due%20Date%20(EDD)%20Rule%20to%20Minimize%20Maximum%20Lateness.php#.WxFGt1OUsmJ) is a discussion which at least includes some cases where EDD fails to minimize the number of tardy jobs.  I haven't gone over them in detail, but perhaps these examples (or simple modifications of them) also fail to minimize the total tardiness.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat extreme example:

One big job, takes 4 days but is unfortunately already due in 2 days, and one small job that takes just 1 day but is due in 3 days. The big job is due first, but if you do that first then both jobs are 2 days late. If you do the small job first then it is in time, and the big job is 3 days late.

So the total amount of tardiness is less by not following EDD (assuming both jobs have the same weight), even though the maximum tardiness is more.

Comment: Thanks for the example. So what you are saying is that Earliest Due Date may not give the minimal tardiness if due date $\lt$ time need to complete the process. But my next question to you is that is it possible for EDD to give a non optimal result is all due dates are $\ge$ time taken to complete the work?

Comment: The same problem can occur later in the schedule if other jobs have to be done first. For a trivial example, suppose it were a week earlier and you also had a job that is due in a week and takes a week to do. I simplified my example to be as small as possible so that and that is the only reason why the schedule is so tight that one of the jobs can't be done in time at the start.